# Tikzpicture with conditioned tikzset

Tags: tikz-pgf, conditionals

I want to have a tikz picture which changes its behaviour depending on the variable \PA. I have two files. One file contains only the tikz picture (Tikz.tex) and a main file which loads the picture via \input as you can see below. To change the depiction, I define a variable called \PA before loading the Tikz-Picture. In the Tikz-Picture I define the style depending on the variable with an ifthenelse-Statement which I put in another definition.

I like to have the node color depending on thie variable \PA as given in the following table:

| \PA | Mechanics-Node | Sensor-Node |
| --- | --- | --- |
| All | Black | Black |
| Mechanic | Black | Gray |
| Sensor | Gray | Black |

I get a lot of errors and all boxes are black! Still the iftheelse-block seems to work correctly as shown via the test-prints of the of the \PAIF-Command.

**Main file:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand{\PAIF}[1]{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\PA}{#1}\or\equal{\PA}{All}}{black}{gray}%
}


\begin{document}
    \newcommand{\PA}{All}
    \noindent\\PA='\PA': Mechanic: \PAIF{Mechanic}; Sensor: \PAIF{Sensor}\\
    \input{Tikz}
    \renewcommand{\PA}{Mechanic}
    \\PA='\PA': Mechanic: \PAIF{Mechanic}; Sensor: \PAIF{Sensor}\\
    \input{Tikz}
    \renewcommand{\PA}{Sensor}
    \\PA='\PA': Mechanic: \PAIF{Mechanic}; Sensor: \PAIF{Sensor}\\
    \input{Tikz}
\end{document}
```

**Tikz-Picture: (Tikz.tex)**

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzset{
            mechanic/.style={\PAIF{Mechanic}},
            sensor/.style={\PAIF{Sensor}},
        }

        \node [draw, rectangle, mechanic] (mech) {Mechanics};
        \node [draw, rectangle, right=of mech, sensor] {Sensors};
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

**Current Result:**

[image: Current, wrong result]

Errors (Only of first node-line in Tikz.tex):

1. Undefined control sequence
2. Extra \or
3. Argument of @tempc has an extra }
4. Paragraph ended before @tempc was complete
5. Paragraph ended before \pgfkeys@addpath was complete
6. Missing \endcsname inserted
7. ...

**Desired Result:**

[image: Desired result]

Comment: In principle `mechanic/.style/.expanded={\PAIF{Mechanic}}` but `\equal` inside `\ifthenelse` is not expandable so this will also not work.

Comment: @HenriMenke Thank you for your hint! I posted a working solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many thanks to @HenriMenke !

I switched from \newcommand to \newcount so I can use \ifnum instead of \ifthenelse with \equal. I am not sure, if this is a "good" solution, but it works!

**Better solution with easy combination of multiple arguments**

I made a slight improvement to my first solution. With this I can make a node black if there is one of two categories matched. So I added something like an OR-Case to my first solution. In princinple this could be extendend to more than two categories easily. Only the if-Statement becomes more and more huge.

**Main File**

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcount\all           \all=0
\newcount\mechanics     \mechanics=1
\newcount\sensors       \sensors=2
\newcount\sthelse       \sthelse=3
\newcount\PA            \PA=\all

\newcommand{\PAIF}[1]{%
    \ifnum\PA=\all%
        black%
    \else%
        \ifnum\PA=#1%
            black%
        \else%
            gray%
        \fi%
    \fi%
}

\newcommand{\PAIFB}[2]{%
    \ifnum\PA=\all%
        black%
    \else%
        \ifnum\PA=#1%
            black%
        \else%
            \ifnum\PA=#2%
                black%
            \else%
                gray%
            \fi%
        \fi%
    \fi%
}


\begin{document}
    \PA = \all
    \\PA=All: Mechanic: \PAIF{\mechanics}; Sensor: \PAIF{\sensors}; Both: \PAIFB{\sensors}{\mechanics}\\
    \input{Tikz}
    
    \PA = \mechanics
    \\PA=Mechanic: Mechanic: \PAIF{\mechanics}; Sensor: \PAIF{\sensors}; Both: \PAIFB{\sensors}{\mechanics}\\
    \input{Tikz}
    
    \PA = \sensors
    \\PA=Sensor: Mechanic: \PAIF{\mechanics}; Sensor: \PAIF{\sensors}; Both: \PAIFB{\sensors}{\mechanics}\\
    \input{Tikz}
    
    \PA = \sthelse
    \\PA=Sthelse: Mechanic: \PAIF{\mechanics}; Sensor: \PAIF{\sensors}; Both: \PAIFB{\sensors}{\mechanics}\\
    \input{Tikz}
\end{document}
```

**Tikz File**

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzset{
            arga/.style n args={1}{\PAIF{#1}},
            argb/.style n args={2}{\PAIFB{#1}{#2}}
        }

        \node [draw, rectangle, arga={\mechanics}] (A) {Mechanics};
        \node [draw, rectangle, right=of A, arga={\sensors}] (B) {Sensors};
        \node [draw, rectangle, right=of B, argb={\mechanics}{\sensors}] (C) {Mechanics or Sensors};
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

---

**First working solution**

**Main File**

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcount\all \all=0
\newcount\mechanics \mechanics=1
\newcount\sensors \sensors=2
\newcount\PA \PA=\all

\newcommand{\PAIF}[1]{%
    \ifnum\PA=\all%
        black%
    \else%
        \ifnum\PA=#1%
            black%
        \else%
            gray%
        \fi%
    \fi%
}


\begin{document}
    \PA = \all
    \\\noindent All: Mechanic: \PAIF{\mechanics}; Sensor: \PAIF{\sensors}\\
    \input{Tikz}
    \PA = \mechanics
    \\Mechanic: Mechanic: \PAIF{\mechanics}; Sensor: \PAIF{\sensors}\\
\input{Tikz}
    \PA = \sensors
    \\Sensor: Mechanic: \PAIF{\mechanics}; Sensor: \PAIF{\sensors}\\
    \input{Tikz}
\end{document}
```

**Tikz File**

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzset{
            mechanic/.style={\PAIF{\mechanics}},
            sensor/.style={\PAIF{\sensors}},
        }

        \node [draw, rectangle, mechanic] (mech) {Mechanics};
        \node [draw, rectangle, right=of mech, sensor] {Sensors};
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```